# Printing of concatenated string with non-string values

Tags: go

This question is simple in scope:

```
fmt.Println("Hello, " + 1 + " World!")
```

will fail with `(mismatched types untyped string and untyped int)`

in this case 1 is not declared but I presume is cast as an integer.  I am coming from PHP BTW.

How do I cast 1 as a string?

Comment: You can't cast an integer value as string in Go. You can use a library function to convert an int to a string, or use `fmt.Printf`

Comment: First, you cna't cast _anything_ in Go, because Go simply doesn't support type casting at all. Second, you can use `fmt.Printf`, `fmt.Println`, or `strconfg.Itoa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fmt.Println("Hello, " + strconv.Itoa(1) + " World!")

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the Sprintf method for such uses, you can use it the same way as printf but instead it outputs a formatted string.

You can use it like so:

```golang
testString := fmt.Sprintf("%s %d %s", "Hello", 1, "World")
```

I hope this was helpful :)